# Result is wrong while finding center of map for v2 android maps?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I am trying to find the center of the map (visible map) on android device using the following code :

```
LatLng mapCenter = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;  // mMap is GoogleMap object
```

Initially my map shows India on screen but it returns me the location of `Giza, Egypt` in **mapCenter**  object. My code has `OnCameraChangeListener` to check further center of map When I scroll or zoom on map .In `OnCameraChangeListener` same code returns the correct center point of map everytime I zoom or scroll on map.Only the first time its returning the wrong location which I am not able to understand why is it happening?Could anyone please guide me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably calling this function just after initializing the mapFragment so that the camera is in its initial position which will points for Giza, Egypt

Comment: @3amoura I am doing this thing after initializing my map and setting location on map to India

Comment: Would you please put some more code , initialization of the map fragment , setting camera position. this would be helpful to let us help you.